# Upgrading php5.3.5 to 5.3.9 in wamp 2.1

Tags: php, wampserver

My wamp server is 2.1 version have 5.3.5 php version.

I want to upgrade the php 5.3.5 to php 5.3.9.

How can i do this?

If there is any chance to miss the files in root directory and also mysql databases?

How can upgrade php 5.3.5 to php5.3.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download php 5.3.9, put the php5.3.9 folder in wampserver, copy your olds file in the new folder:

```
php.ini
phpForApache.ini
wampserver.conf
```

edit (replace your actually version with the new one in this two files)

```
php.ini
phpForApache.ini
```

Backup and delete /bin/apache/apache/apache2.2.11/php.ini

Restart wamp (it is possible to run after first restart, the older version) Restart again you wamp, and check phpinfo()

(restart from console...)

Comment: so do you mean we can seperately upgrade php in wamp 2.1? if there is any need to upgrade the wamp also?

Comment: No, you don't need a wamp upgrade. Protect your work...backup it before upgrade php. And yes...you can.